How to implement the layout of authors from different institutions and co-first authors/corresponding authors in LaTeX?
As the title says, I want to achieve the effects shown in the following two figures (where Figure 2 is a footnote).


following is my MWE code.
I have tried using the \footnotemark command, but it conflicts with the authblk package. Perhaps I can only use the not-so-smart method of $^\dagger$. I would like to ask if you have any better methods or suggestions? Thank you very much.
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[fontset=ubuntu]{ctexart}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{authblk} 
\date{\zhtoday}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\renewcommand*{\Authsep}{，}
\renewcommand*{\Authand}{，}
\renewcommand*{\Authands}{，}

\begin{document}
\title{中文标题}

\author[1]{甲$^\dagger$}
\author[2]{乙}
\author[3]{丙\thanks{通讯作者： 丙（电话:…… , Email:……@abc.com）}}

\affil[1]{X学院，X大学，北京；}
\affil[2]{Y学院，Y大学，上海；}
\affil[3]{Z学院，Z大学，广州；}
\maketitle

% 重新定义摘要标题的内容及格式
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\vspace{-2em}\large\bf 摘要}
\begin{abstract}
这是摘要， 这是摘要， 这是摘要， 这是摘要， 这是摘要， 这是摘要， 这是摘要， 这是摘要， 这是摘要， 这是摘要， 这是摘要， 这是摘要， 这是摘要， 这是摘要， 这是摘要， 这是摘要， 这是摘要，
\end{abstract}

{\bf 关键词：}关键词1、关键词2、关键词3

\begin{center}
{\Large \bf English Title\par\vspace*{15pt}}
{\large\lineskip .5em   X\textsuperscript{1},~Y\textsuperscript{2},~Z\footnotemark[1]\textsuperscript{3}}\\
\textsuperscript{1}~{School of X} \\
\textsuperscript{2}~{School of Y} \\
\textsuperscript{3}~{School of Z} \\
\end{center}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\large\bf Abstract}
\begin{abstract}
this is abstract，this is abstract，this is abstract，this is abstract，this is abstract，this is abstract，this is abstract，this is abstract，this is abstract，this is abstract，this is abstract，this is abstract，this is abstract，this is abstract，this is abstract，this is abstract，this is abstract，this is abstract
\end{abstract}

{\bf Keywords：}
Keyword A，Keyword B，Keyword C
\vspace{3em}

\section*{引言}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}


Have a look here https://ctan.org/pkg/titlepages, which provides many examples and code. Also have a look here https://ctan.org/topic/titlepage . // For the titlepage you can do without \footnote.

Unfortunately it's no simple task to get your posted code running in a different environment than yours. So here is one approach based on the titlepage environment. I assume:

you won't need the predefined variables
i.e. \title, \author etc. will never again be mentioned in your text
so you can drop them and treat the titlepage as just another page to typeset
you don't need to hyperlink "footnotes"; if so, use package hyperref

Some remarks
My skeleton just duplicates English text, while you'd put Japanese where you need it.
Do further vertical alignment the way you want, e.g. using \bigskip, \vspace, \stretch etc.
The title shows one way to change font locally.
The "footnotes" are just plain text, as indicated earlier. You could introduce them manually, like so:
...
Writer A$^{1\#}$, W ...
...
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        $^{\#}$ joint first author  & joint first author\\
        \expo{*} Corresponding author: B (Tel, Email) &Corresponding author: B (Tel, Email)\\
    \end{tabular}   

or more systematically via a \newcommand:
...
\newcommand\expo[1]{${}^{#1}$}
...
Writer A\expo{1\#}, Writer B\expo{2\#}, Writer C\expo{3*}
...

Centering enumerated lists seems to be somewhat special. So I replaced them by a poor mans approach to specify horizontal indenting, which can certainly be done better ... while it's a short list anyway:
    % ~~~ poor mans approach: shift + set labels manually
    \begin{list}{}{\setlength\leftmargin{48mm}}
     \item[1.] Afiliation Number 1
     \item[2.] Afiliation 2     
     \item[3.] Afiliation 3
    \end{list}


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\large\bf Abstract}

\newcommand\expo[1]{${}^{#1}$}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
 % ~~~ put Japanese here ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        {\Huge{\textbf{Something}}}
        \bigskip
        
        Writer A\expo{1\#}, Writer B\expo{2\#}, Writer C\expo{3*}

    \end{center} 
    
    % ~~~ poor mans approach: shift + set labels manually
    \begin{list}{}{\setlength\leftmargin{48mm}}
     \item[1.] Afiliation Number 1
     \item[2.] Afiliation 2     
     \item[3.] Afiliation 3
    \end{list}
    \bigskip

    % ~~~ put English here ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~     
    \begin{center}
        {\Large{\textbf{\textsf{Title}}}}
        \bigskip
     
        Writer A$^{1\#}$, Writer B, Writer C
    \end{center}    
    
    % ~~~ poor mans approach: shift + set labels manually
    \begin{list}{}{\setlength\leftmargin{48mm}}
     \item[1.] Afiliation Number 1
     \item[2.] Afiliation 2     
     \item[3.] Afiliation 3
    \end{list}
    \bigskip

    \bigskip\hrule\bigskip
    
    % ~~~ Just one approach: you may need pagebreaks per column ~~~
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        $^{\#}$ joint first author  & joint first author\\
        \expo{*} Corresponding author: B (Tel, Email) &Corresponding author: B (Tel, Email)\\
    \end{tabular}   
    
 \end{titlepage}

 % ~~~ content ~~~~~~~~~~~
 \tableofcontents
 
 \begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[12]
 \end{abstract}


 \section{Some section}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}


Thank you for your answer! and by the way ,I'm Chinese not Japanese.

Thank you. So my second guess would have been more accurate …
